# Cloning objects in Java [3 questions]

Tags: java, class, abstract-class, clone

will the clone method of Asub be called by doing this? Or is Asub deep cloned properly? If not, is there a way to propery deep clone Asub through this kind of method?

```
abstract class Top extends TopMost {
    protected Object clone() {
        Object obj = super.clone();
        // deep copy and try catch
    }


}

abstract class A extends Top { 
    protected Object clone() {
        Object obj = super.clone();
       // deep copy and try catch
    } 


}

class Asub extends A {
    protected Object clone() {
        Object obj = super.clone();
        // deep copy and try catch
    }

    public void doSomethingNew() {
    }
}

abstract class TopMost {
    public void someMethod() {
        Top a = (Top) super.clone();
        // more code here
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Asub class1 = new Asub();
        class1.someMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By allowing all `abstract` subclasses implementing `super.clone()` essentially does nothing (since all your abstract classes in your example are doing nothing) and just call (at the end) `Object.clone()` method.

My suggestion is to allow all concrete classes (like ASub) to override the clone method and use the [copy constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor) idiom to create an exact clone of itself....

e.g.

```
public abstract class TopMost {

    public TopMost(TopMost rhs) {

    }

}

public abstract class Top extends TopMost {

    public Top(Top rhs) {
        super(rhs);

        //whatever you need from rhs that only is visible from top
    }
}

public abstract class A extends Top { 

    public A (A rhs) {
        super(rhs);

        //TODO: do rhs copy
    }
}

public class ASub extends A {

    public ASub(ASub rhs) {
        super(rhs);

        //TODO: copy other stuff here....
    }

    public Object clone() {
        return new ASub(this);
    }
}
```

**PS** Make `TopMost` **Cloneable**

Comment: Unfortunately if `ASub` is subclassed further, the subclass' `clone()` may not call `super.clone()`, as it returns an `ASub` instead of an `ASubSub`. So this only works if one has complete control over the whole class hierarchy, forever (and has carefully documented the nonconformant `clone` implementation for his/her successors).

Comment: @Péter Török, I fully agree with you.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, note that **[the clone() interface is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627053/speeding-up-java-deep-copy-operations/3627093#3627093)**, thus should not be used in new code. It is better to **implement copy constructor(s) instead**.

However, if you *really* need to do it, the proper way is for `TopMost` to implement `Cloneable`. Why? Says Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 11:

> So what does `Cloneable` do, given that it contains no methods? It determines
>   the behavior of `Object`’s protected `clone` implementation: if a class implements
>   `Cloneable`, `Object`’s clone method returns a field-by-field copy of the object;
>   otherwise it throws `CloneNotSupportedException`.This is a highly atypical use
>   of interfaces and not one to be emulated. Normally, implementing an interface
>   says something about what a class can do for its clients. In the case of `Cloneable`,
>   it modifies the behavior of a protected method on a superclass.

Moreover, `Asub.clone` should be declared `public`, not `protected` - otherwise you can't call it from the outside world. Also, if you are using Java5 or above, it is legal and desirable for `Asub.clone` to return `Asub`, not `Object` (and similarly for its superclasses).

You don't show any members in the classes - the implementations of `clone` in the various classes can be a whole lot different depending on the types of members in that class. Namely, if a class has any mutable members, you need to carefully deep copy all of them, otherwise you end up with distinct objects sharing their internal state.

However, supposing your classes have only primitive or immutable fields, the cloning works as expected, although you have a lot of unnecessary `clone` methods in your abstract classes, all of which simply call `super.clone()` - you may be better off with `Asub.clone()` only.

As a side note, if `Top a = (Top) super.clone()` is not a typo, you introduce a dependency from base class to derived class, which is not a good idea.

Comment: Yes and `maybe` not because `Cloneable` is just a marker interface.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman, unfortunately `Cloneable` is not just a marker interface. See my update.

Comment: @Péter Török, so in summary, Asub is deepy cloned, all fields including those from the abstract classes were given a new reference and a copy?

Comment: @Joset, nope...since you're calling `super.clone()`.

Comment: @Joset, in its current form, `Asub.clone()` is creating a _shallow clone_. The values of all fields are _copied_ into the new object. This is adequate for primitive (e.g. `int`) or immutable (e.g. `String`) fields only. But any mutable objects must be deep copied by hand.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `super.clone()` disables the virtual mechanism, so it only calls `Object.clone()`

Comment: sorry removed the other someMethod it should be in TopMost only