# Does a subclass need to override the clone() method explicitly if the superclass has already done it?

Tags: java, clone

If `class A extends class B` and `class B` has already implemented the `Cloneable` interface, then is it necessary for `class A` to declare '`clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException`'?

I guess it should not be mandatory, as the property to clone objects of `class A` would automatically be inherited from `class B`.

Answer (score 2):

It is necessary to override `clone()` if class B defines non-primitve mutable member fields. These need to be deep copied explicitly within `B.clone()`. If B only contains primitive and/or immutable data members, `A.clone()` will do the job.

For a more detailed explanation, see [this earlier answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652748/cloning-objects-in-java-3-questions/3652767#3652767) to a similar question.

Comment: If you're calling _super.clone_ in every _clone_ implementation, then you'll eventually call _Object#clone_. And that method will make shallow copy of all data fields. I think, OP has got it right.

Comment: @Nikita, the first version of my answer was incorrect indeed, but I have since updated it, now I believe it is right.

Comment: If any of `B`'s ancestors define `clone` in terms of a copy constructor rather than in terms of `Object`, then `B` must do likewise.  If `B` uses a copy constructor even though all its ancestors chain to `base.clone`, it compels all of its descendents to likewise use a copy constructor.  Personally, I find irksome the notion of clone methods that do anything other than chaining to `base.clone`, but such methods are alas very common.

Answer (score 0):

If the parent class, and all ancestors, implements its `Clone` method by calling its parent class' `Clone` method, all the way up to `Object.clone`, and if none of the fields added by the subclass hold references to things which should be changeable on one object without affecting the other, then one can simply inherit clone without overriding it.  If the parent class implements the clone method as described above but the subclass adds fields that themselves need to be cloned, the best pattern is for the subclass to call `base.Clone` and then clone the appropriate fields.

If the parent class or any ancestor does not implement its `Clone` method as described above but instead uses a copy constructor, then the derived class, and all base classes derived from it) must override `Clone` to do likewise, regardless of whether the base class adds any new fields.

Unfortunately, I know of no nice way to ascertain which category a parent class belongs to.  If a parent class supports `Clone` by calling `base.Clone`, it would be unfortunate for a derived class to needlessly break the chain by implementing a copy constructor.  On the other hand, if the parent class implements `Clone` as a copy constructor, a base class which does not do so will have broken semantics.