# How does the clone() method access an object's fields? (Java)

Tags: java, reflection, clone, subclass, native-code

I have a question regarding the clone() method in Java. First of all, **I do know** the clone method is broken and all the rest but we're studying this topic at school and I want to get a tight grip of it (even though it may not be the most effective way of doing things).

Let's assume I'm in a situation like this:

```
public class A implements Cloneable {
    private int a;
    private int b;

    // constructors, methods, etc.

    @Override
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone()
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    private String c;
    private String d;

    // constructors and all the rest

    @Override
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone()
    }
}
```

Now, if in my main() I had something like:

```
B test1 = new B();
B test2 = (B) test1.clone();
```

I know from experience that the `clone()` method would make a copy of **all** the values of test1; in fact, I can access and modify `int a`, `int b`, `String c` and `String d` thanks to the appropriate get/set methods.

What I don't really get is why this all works that way. I mean: when I run the `clone()` from B it makes a call to the `clone()` from A, which in turn makes a call to Object's `clone()` which returns **an object that is a shallow copy of test1**. Such object is then returned to A's `clone()` which returns it to B's `clone()` which returns it.

Now, where does this copying happen and what is copied? A and B's `clone()` don't actually do anything (or technically any **copying**). B's method just makes a call to A's method which in turn makes a call to Object's. The [first answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3986606/2397616) I found yesterday reinforces my belief about the necessity of A and B's `clone()` methods, stating that in that particular case (which happens to be the same as mine), B's `clone()` wouldn't even be necessary at all.

Fair enough, this means Object's `clone()` is the one that does **all the copying**. Point now is: how does Object's `clone()` see **all** of the necessary fields?

I humbly hypothesized that it was because Object is a superclass of B, but that kind of thinking doesn't really stand. In fact, A is a superclass of B too but I can't access B's private fields if it wasn't for the get/set methods I put inside B. And Object's `clone()` surely doesn't work based on my get/set methods.

- Is there something I'm missing here or am I just trying to understand something which is considerably over my head?
- Is the `clone()` method in Object some sort of "special" method or something?
- Can I take it as an axiom from now on that Object's `clone()` makes a shallow copy of **all the fields** of an Object? (being them private or only visible in a subclass/superclass or whatever else...)

(Please provide references if you can. It's not that I don't trust you, it's just that I've searched through all my textbooks and online too and I'd really like to know where to look the next time I have a question like this! ;) )

Comment: clone method in Object class has implemented natively, however for better info you would check [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Object.java)

Comment: if you have any reference of an object you can check every private members very easy with reflection

Comment: The `clone` method isn't "broken". It is simply designed to do a very specific operation that is not the correct operation in many of the cases that programmers are tempted to use/override it.

Comment: thank you guys! haven't really looked into reflection yet. that's a nice input! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The javadoc of clone() explains what Object.clone() does:

> The method clone for class Object performs a specific cloning operation. First, if the class of this object does not implement the interface Cloneable, then a CloneNotSupportedException is thrown. Note that all arrays are considered to implement the interface Cloneable. Otherwise, this method creates a new instance of the class of this object and initializes all its fields with exactly the contents of the corresponding fields of this object, as if by assignment; the contents of the fields are not themselves cloned. Thus, this method performs a "shallow copy" of this object, not a "deep copy" operation.

The `clone()` method is a *native* method (just look in [the sources](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java)). It's implemented in native code, by the JVM, which of course has access to all the state of the object being cloned. Note that even Java code using reflection also has access to all the state, even private, of any object.