# Why I must override clone if i want cloneable class?

Tags: java, object, clone

Why I must override clone if i want cloneable class? All classes extends from `Object`, so why I must override the Object clone method? Why I cant just invoke the original Object clone method?

Comment: You might want to checkout this answer as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652748/cloning-objects-in-java-3-questions/3652767#3652767

Comment: You can always write a copy method in your class.  You don't have to override anything.

Answer (score 8):

It's one of the many "design flaws" in the JDK.

`Clonable` should have been an interface with a `clone()` method, but instead it's a [marker interface](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern) and `Object` has a "do nothing" implementation of the `clone()` method... and you're left with your question.

If you're interested, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7284322/256196) lists some other "mistakes" in java.

Answer (score 1):

See here: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html

Invoking Object's clone method on an instance that does not implement the Cloneable interface results in the exception CloneNotSupportedException being thrown.

Also I guess this discussion would be helpful for you: 
[Confusion about cloneable interface and object.clone() in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067383/confusion-about-cloneable-interface-and-object-clone-in-java)