# How many types of cloning an object are available in java?

Tags: java

How many types of cloning an object are available in java?

Comment: consider to accept more answers to get better answers :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Two types of cloning***

***Read Bozho's answer***
[java-recommended-solution-for-deep-cloning-copying-an-instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156120/java-recommended-solution-for-deep-cloning-copying-an-instance)

*Some Interesting Topic on [faster deep copies](http://javatechniques.com/blog/faster-deep-copies-of-java-objects/)*

**Shallow Cloning**

> it is a bit-wise copy of an object. A
>   new object is created that has an
>   exact copy of the values in the
>   original object. If any of the fields
>   of the object are references to other
>   objects, just the references are
>   copied. Thus, if the object you are
>   copying contains references to yet
>   other objects, a shallow copy refers
>   to the same subobjects.

**Deep Cloning.**

> Deep copy is a complete duplicate copy
>   of an object. If an object has
>   references to other objects, complete
>   new copies of those objects are also
>   made. A deep copy generates a copy not
>   only of the primitive values of the
>   original object, but copies of all
>   subobjects as well, all the way to the
>   bottom. If you need a true, complete
>   copy of the original object, then you
>   will need to implement a full deep
>   copy for the object.
>
> Java supports shallow and deep copy
>   with the Cloneable interface to create
>   copies of objects. To make a clone of
>   a Java object, you declare that an
>   object implements Cloneable, and then
>   provide an override of the clone
>   method of the standard Java Object
>   base class. Implementing Cloneable
>   tells the java compiler that your
>   object is Cloneable. The cloning is
>   actually done by the clone method.

**how many ways to create object.**

- Serialization
- clone() method
- new operator copy constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Shallow Copy

Generally clone method of an object, creates a new instance of the same class and copies all the fields to the new instance and returns it. This is nothing but shallow copy. Object class provides a clone method and provides support for the shallow copy. It returns ‘Object’ as type and you need to explicitly cast back to your original object.

Since the Object class has the clone method (protected) you cannot use it in all your classes. The class which you want to be cloned should implement clone method and overwrite it. It should provide its own meaning for copy or to the least it should invoke the super.clone(). Also you have to implement Cloneable marker interface or else you will get CloneNotSupportedException. When you invoke the super.clone() then you are dependent on the Object class’s implementation and what you get is a shallow copy.

Deep Copy

When you need a deep copy then you need to implement it yourself. When the copied object contains some other object its references are copied recursively in deep copy. When you implement deep copy be careful as you might fall for cyclic dependencies. If you don’t want to implement deep copy yourselves then you can go for serialization. It does implements deep copy implicitly and gracefully handling cyclic dependencies.

One more disadvantage with this clone system is that, most of the interface / abstract class writers in java forget to put a public clone method. For example you can take List. So when you want to clone their implementations you have to ignore the abstract type and use actual implementations like ArrayList by name. This completely removes the advantage and goodness of abstractness.

When implementing a singleton pattern, if its superclass implements a public clone() method, to prevent your subclass from using this class’s clone() method to obtain a copy overwrite it and throw an exception of type  CloneNotSupportedException.

Note that clone is not for instantiation and initialization. It should not be synonymously used as creating a new object. Because the constructor of the cloned objects may never get invoked in the process. It is about copying the object in discussion and not creating new. It completely depends on the clone implementation. One more disadvantage (what to do there are so many), clone prevents the use of final fields. We have to find roundabout ways to copy the final fields into the copied object.

Clone is an agreement between you, compiler and implementer. If you are confident that you all three have good knowledge of java, then go ahead and use clone. If you have a slightest of doubt better copy the object manually.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to implement Cloneable.

Or you can go for deepCopy or shalowCopy depending on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The "obvious" answer suggested by your question would be to implement the `Cloneable` interface and override `Object.clone()`. However, [this API is obsolete and broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627053/speeding-up-java-deep-copy-operations/3627093#3627093), thus shouldn't be used in new code.

Probably the best - most "mainstream", thus easiest to understand and use - way would be to implement a *copy constructor*.

Of course one can implement a totally custom - static or nonstatic - cloning method, under whatever name (s)he prefers, using deep or shallow copy. Just this would be much less idiomatic, thus harder to learn and use, so it is not recommended.