# why arraylist clear to temporery as well as original?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am working with arrayList data.so I have 4 array list.I have 3 arraylist are fill with data one of as for temporery store arraylist as per selection. my code is below.

```
            if(App.SubPosition==0){
                if(custList.size()>0)
                    custList1=custList;
            }
            if(App.SubPosition==1){
                if(custList.size()>0)
                    custList2=custList;
            }
            if(App.SubPosition==2){
                if(custList.size()>0)
                    custList3=custList;
            }
            App.SubPosition = position;
            String json = null;
            //custList.clear();
            Log.e("Log","custList1="+custList1.size());
            Log.e("Log","custList2="+custList2.size());
            Log.e("Log","custList3="+custList3.size());
            Log.e("Log","custList3="+custList.size());

            custList.clear();

            Log.e("Log","custList1="+custList1.size());
            Log.e("Log","custList2="+custList2.size());
            Log.e("Log","custList3="+custList3.size());
            Log.e("Log","custList3="+custList.size());
```

run above code it will display log as per below.

[image]

If I  clear only custlist then it is also clear to custlist1 arraylist.

why is it happen?

***Your answer would be appreciated***

Comment: You never have multiple lists. You have one list and multiple references to that list.

Comment: Because you're referencing the same list. You haven't copied anything.

Comment: how can i do copy arrayList to another arraylist object?

Comment: You can use `custListN.addAll(custList)` instead of `custList1=custList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use addAll() method.

```
if(App.SubPosition==0){
    if(custList.size()>0)
        custList1.addAll(custList);
}
if(App.SubPosition==1){
    if(custList.size()>0)
        custList2.addAll(custList);
}
if(App.SubPosition==2){
    if(custList.size()>0)
        custList3.addAll(custList);
}
```

You can use clone() as well.

Comment: I find the lack of braces disturbing

Comment: I find the suggested use of [`clone()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802118/why-we-use-clone-method-in-java) disturbing.

Comment: It should be noted that this will append data to whatever was initially in those lists

Answer (score 1):

You never have multiple lists. You have one list and multiple references to that list.

You can create a copy using

```
custList1 = new ArrayList<>(custList);
```

This creates a new `ArrayList` instance, copying the data.

Answer (score 1):

You are using different names for the same ArrayList. Instead of that, try to do something like:

```
ArrayList<whatever> copy = new ArrayList<>();
copy.addAll(originalArray);
```

or

```
ArrayList<whatever> copy = new ArrayList<>(originalArray);
```

**NOTE:** do a *new* every time you want a "copy", since if you don't, you will be adding every element multiple times and will have a huge array instead of a copy.

Comment: You can simply do `new ArrayList<>(originalArray)`.