# What is the use of Cloning in JAVA and where it is frequently used?

Tags: java, oop, clone, abstract, comparable

I have used programming and understood that cloning means the duplication of a object. But, I could not get idea about in what context and where it is mainly used? I mean, where does it appear to be used?

```
public abstract class GeometricObject { 
    private String color = "white";
    private boolean filled;

    //Default constructor
    protected GeometricObject(){

    }
    //Constructing a Geometric object
    protected GeometricObject(String color, boolean filled){
        this.color = color;
        this.filled = filled;
    }
    //Getter method for color
    public String getColor(){
        return color;
    }
    //set method for color
    public void setColor(String color){
        this.color = color;
    }
    //Getter method for filled
    public boolean isFilled(){
        return filled;
    }
    //setter method for filled
    public void setFilled(boolean filled){
        this.filled = filled;
    }
    //Abstract method for getting Area
    public abstract double getArea();

    //Abstract method for getting perimeter
    public abstract double getPerimeter();

}

public class Octagon extends GeometricObject implements Comparable<Octagon> , Cloneable {
    private double sides;
    //Default constructor
    public Octagon(){

    }

    /**New Octagon Object**/
    public Octagon(double side){
        this.sides = side;
    }

    /**Getter method**/
    public double getSide(){
        return sides;
    }

    /**Setter method**/
    public void setSide(double side){
        this.sides = side;
    }


    @Override
    public double getArea() {
        double area = (2*(1+(Math.sqrt(2)))*sides*sides);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return area;
    }

    @Override
    public double getPerimeter() {
        double perimeter = sides * 8;
        return perimeter;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Octagon o) {
        if(getArea()>o.getArea())
            return 1;
        else if(getArea()<o.getArea())
            return -1;
        else 
            return 0;
    }
    @Override
     public Object clone() {
            try {
              return super.clone();
            }
            catch (CloneNotSupportedException ex) {
              return null;
            }
          }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /**Creating a new Ocatgon object of having side value 5**/
        Octagon oct = new Octagon(7);
        //getting Area of new octagon
        System.out.println("The area of Octagon with side 5.0 is (A): "+ oct.getArea());
        /**Getting perimeter of new Octagon**/
        System.out.println("The perimeter of Octagon with side 5.0 is (P): "+ oct.getPerimeter());
        /*
         * Creating a new object using clone method and 
         * copy of oct whose side is 5
        */
        Octagon octagon1 = (Octagon)oct.clone();

        /*
         * comparing the two objects i.e.  using compareTo method.
         */
        int i= oct.compareTo(octagon1);
        if(i<0){
            System.out.println("Clone Octagon is grater than original octagon");
        }else if(i>0)
            System.out.println("Clone octagon is smaller than original octagon");
        else
            System.out.println("Clone octagon is Equal to original octagon");   
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your code have to do with the question?

Comment: i have done this programming myself. The question here I am asking is, where does the clone mostly used. Just dont see the code. Give me example on why you use cloning?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why we use clone() method in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5802118/5221149)

Comment: Could you explain why you (and so many others) call it JAVA when its name is actually, really, honestly, seriously, not an acronym?

Comment: As for examples of `clone()` use, see javadoc: [Uses of Interface
java.lang.Cloneable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/class-use/Cloneable.html)

Comment: In addition, please explain what the random code dump has to do with your question. If you have a question about your code, write an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ask about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to `clone` an `object` your class should implement  `Cloneable` interface and you should override `clone` method from object class which is weird, clone method should have been on the Cloneable interface . your implementation on Clone method and using the cloned object is correct. i assume you are not getting the concept `Duplication of objects` . for an example

you have  an object of octagon `Octagon octagon1 = new Octagen();;`

and you have a referrence of `Octagon octagon2 = octagon1;`

even though `octagon1` and `octagon2` are 2 different variables they are keeping referrence on the same object. if you make a change to the object using any variable , the change will affect the 2 variables since they referring to the same object.

```
octagon2.setSide(2);
octagon1.getSide(); //will return 2.
```

by cloning the objects you won't end up with above problem.

```
 Octagon oct = new Octagon(7);
 Octagon octagon1 = (Octagon)oct.clone();

octagon1.setSide(3);
oct.getSide(); //will not return 3 because they are not referring to the same object.
```

Comment: That means object will be duplicated without disturbing the original one. I hope I got it now. Thanks a lot dude!!