# Clonning String array, checking the refs

Tags: java, clone

Cloning the String arrays, using clone() method on java array. After cloning I'm expecting to have new Strings in new array - with new addresses allocated for them. But... I got a bit different behavior, plz look at this:

(It will print:

```
same address
One
```

)

```
public class ArrayCopyClone {

    static String[] array2 = new String[] {"One", "Two", "Three"};

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] copy2 = array2.clone();

        if (copy2[0] != array2[0])  {
            System.out.println("good");   // will never show up
        } else {
           System.out.println("same address");  // I'm expecting never be here
        }

        array2[0] = "new";

        System.out.println(copy2[0]); // "One", and this is OK (it means we have a copy)

    }

}
```

Is it related to string-shadowing? Should it be?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821851/does-calling-clone-on-an-array-also-clone-its-contents

Comment: Why do you care?  Strings are immutable; there's no difference between  any string and any copy of that string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloning an array gives a shallow copy.  So the contents are identical.  For deep cloning see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156120/java-recommended-solution-for-deep-cloning-copying-an-instance/2156367#2156367).

Answer (score 0):

First, by default `clone()` is not implemented as a "deep clone", so it copies sub-objects as references. Moreover strings are cached by JDK. You are exposing 2 these effects.

Comment: I don't think string caching comes into play in this example; any other type of object in the arrays would exhibit the same effect.