# Android: error when using int array passed into class

Tags: android, arrays, view, android-activity, int

I am passing an int array from one class to another but am getting an error when I try to access values from it. I have no idea why, hopefully someone can enlighten me?

Here's the first class that calls the second:

```
public class ConvertToGrid extends Activity{

DrawGrid v;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...code...
    int[] binArray = {Color.RED, Color.WHITE, Color.YELLOW, ...};

    v = new DrawGrid(this, binArray);
    setContentView(v);
}}
```

This calls my DrawGrid View:

```
public class DrawGrid extends View{

private int[] binary;

public DrawGrid(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public DrawGrid(Context context, int[] inBinary) {
    super(context);
    binary = inBinary.clone();
}

int sq00c = binary[0];
...etc}
```

What am I doing wrong such that it cannot access this int array called binary? If I move the int array into DrawGrid it accesses the cells without any trouble, but passing it through with my construct seems to make it inaccessible. In case anyone asks, I can't just define the array in DrawGrid as it is defined by the code in ConvertGrid.

Perhaps I am going about this in the wrong way and there is a better way to pass the int array? Thanks

Edit:

LogCat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(12035): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(12035): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{bras2756.ox.ac.uk.colourgrid/bras2756.ox.ac.uk.colourgrid.ConvertToGrid}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: It's important that you show what error you're getting. Give us the output from logcat.

Comment: I've added what I assume is the relevant LogCat line.

Comment: Doesn't that NullPointerException give you a line number?

Comment: change private int[] binary to protected int[] binary or create a getter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that because your `int sq00c = binary[0];` type statements are outside a method body, and hence get executed before your constructor is called, which makes the `binary` array empty. So when you try to access data in it, you'll get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception.

Try using:

```
public class DrawGrid extends View{

    private int[] binary;
    private int sq00c;
    etc....

    public DrawGrid(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public DrawGrid(Context context, int[] inBinary) {
        super(context);
        binary = inBinary;
        sq00c = binary[0];
        ...etc
    }
}
```

I've split the int declaration and the assignment into two. The ints are still declared at the class level, but are only given a value when the constructor is called.

Comment: Aaaarrrrrghhhh.  Another outbreak of the "global" disease.  We need an antidote now.  This is not global, it's a class level variable.  A global, by definition, has scope and lifetime equal to the application.  If we don't care about being accurate and correct, then why do we try to develop software?

Comment: @Simon Better? My apologies for the incorrect terminology. Completely self taught, so dont' really know what to call them. I do know what's what though.

Comment: Yeh, +1 for being a good Overflower, a quick fix and being self taught ;) (PS.  I voted for you)

Comment: That's great, thanks. Teaching myself also so I really appreciate the odd clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

By seeing the exception seems like this is your problem

Clone() create a shallow copy check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821851/does-calling-clone-on-an-array-also-clone-its-contents)

I think following modification will solve your problem

```
public DrawGrid(Context context, int[] inBinary) {
super(context);
binary = inBinary; //update to this
}
```