# Can Java's Array clone() return null?

Tags: java, android, arrays, clone

Given this code:

```
public class SoundAndFilterCollection {

    private final Sound[] sounds;
    private final Filter[] filters;

    public SoundAndFilterCollection(Sound[] sounds, Filter[] filters) {
        this.sounds = sounds.clone();
        this.filters = filters.clone();

        Arrays.sort(sounds);
        Arrays.sort(filters);
    }

    public Sound[] getSounds() {
        return sounds.clone();
    }

    public Filter[] getFilters() {
        return filters.clone();
    }
}
```

I'm having a NullPointerException when doing getSounds():

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object gab[].clone()' on a null object reference
at com.mycompany.messenger.push2talk.domain.SoundAndFilterCollection.getSounds(SoundAndFilterCollection.java:24)
at com.mycompany.messenger.shareinchat.chatbar.hiddenpanel.views.soundstickers.presenter.SoundStickersPanelPresenter.setSoundsViews(SoundStickersPanelPresenter.java:92)
at com.mycompany.messenger.shareinchat.chatbar.hiddenpanel.views.soundstickers.presenter.SoundStickersPanelPresenter.access$000(SoundStickersPanelPresenter.java:20)
at com.mycompany.messenger.shareinchat.chatbar.hiddenpanel.views.soundstickers.presenter.SoundStickersPanelPresenter.access$200(SoundStickersPanelPresenter.java:20)
at com.mycompany.messenger.shareinchat.chatbar.hiddenpanel.views.soundstickers.presenter.SoundStickersPanelPresenter$3.onDoneWithContext(SoundStickersPanelPresenter.java:59)
at com.mycompany.messenger.shareinchat.chatbar.hiddenpanel.views.soundstickers.presenter.SoundStickersPanelPresenter$3.onDoneWithContext(SoundStickersPanelPresenter.java:56)
at com.mycompany.deferred.Done$UIContextual.onDone(Done.java:35)
```

My question is: how can I have a null object in getSounds() with this implementation? I've tested Array clone() in JDK 1.8 and in a couple of Android devices and it's never returning null.

About the 2 Arrays.sort() I'm aware that they're sorting the wrong reference and I don't think they're relevant for this crash, but I wanted to share the code just like it is.

PS: Also, I'm having this crash in a huge variety of phones, so I don't think it is related with a strange implementation of clone() in a modified phone.

Comment: And just to clarify, `sounds` passed in via the constructor isn't `null`?

Comment: Does your Sound class implement Clonable ?

Comment: Have a look at [Does calling clone() on an array also clone its contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821851/does-calling-clone-on-an-array-also-clone-its-contents)

Comment: @MichaelDodd if it were null, we will have a NPE when building the object

Comment: @MickMnemonic but in that case I will have an empty array with wrongly cloned sounds, right?

Comment: Where are your Sound and Filter Classes?

Comment: Are they relevant for this? they're just POJOs implementing Comparable. But if you think I should add them to the question I will :)

Answer (score 0):

Mystery solved, this class was being instantiated with Gson in a cache, as I've seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18645370/1668144) this is possible even without an empty constructor.

This class was obfuscated with proguard so it wasn't able to recover the serialized info and it was initialized with null values