# Why isn't there a easy way to copy objects in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, object, reference, copy

I have a class TimeLine in my GUI. I have a function where I would like to copy this TimeLine and modify the data in it whithout the TImeLine in my GUI won't be affected.

I've searched some forums and haven't found an easy way because Java let's the references stick. Why isn't there a easy way to create a new Object (TimeLine) that hasn't the reference to the previous one?

Please help my make a copy of this TimeLine object!

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156120/java-recommended-solution-for-deep-cloning-copying-an-instance/2156367#2156367

Comment: Is it a simple copy only requirement or there is something else where you are facing problem at ?

Answer (score 4):

The [`clone()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29) method and [`Cloneable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) interface, suggested by other authors here, were created with the incorrect assumption that it would be a good idea to have a generic copying method. The default implementations does a shallow clone of the current object, but you could override it to do a deep clone.

There is no correct, generic way to copy arbitrary objects, what you want to copy depends on the objects involved. For example, immutable objects never need copying (that'd just be a waste of space), while some types of objects *can't* be copied (how would you copy a `FileOutputStream`, for example?).

The way I find most elegant is immutable objects with methods that return a copy with just one field changed:

```
class Pony {
    private final String name;
    private final Color color;
    private final int tailLength;

    // constructors and accessors omitted

    Pony withName(String newName) {
        return new Pony(newName, color, tailLength);
    }

    Pony withColor(Color newColor) {
        return new Pony(name, newColor, tailLength);
    }

    Pony withTailLength(String newTailLength) {
        return new Pony(name, color, newTailLength);
    }
}

// Usage:

Pony tony = new Pony("Tony", Color.DAPPLE, 32);
Pony maurice = tony.withName("Maurice") // Maurice is like Tony, but black.
                   .withColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Unfortunately, you get a lot of boilerplate this way, and there's no mainstream IDE support either (there may be plugins, though). Related to this is the [Builder pattern](http://rwhansen.blogspot.com/2007/07/theres-builder-pattern-that-joshua.html) recommended by Josh Bloch in Effective Java.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `clone()` you might want to consider writing a copy constructor for your class:

```
public TimeLine(TimeLine original) {
    this.foo = original.foo;
    this.bar = original.bar;
}
```

Be careful when copying the value of any reference fields in your class.  Be sure whether you want a shallow copy or a deep copy.

Answer (score 2):

In Java using the operator "=" your are simply copying references to objects. If you want to implement copy by value use  clone operation (clone() method of the class Object) or implement your own clone method (overriding the implemented one).

Pay attention that if your class stores other object inside it, these objects should eventually be cloned too (DEEP COPY).

Comment: The '=' operator doesn't copy objects at all, it copies references. You need to reword this.

Comment: @EJP : haven't I used the words "copy by reference" ?

Comment: Partially quoting yourself doesn't change anything. You have used the words 'objects are always copied by reference(using "=" operator)'. They aren't. The '=' operator doesn't 'copy objects by reference' at all. It copies references by value. It's not the same thing. Downvoting.

Comment: @EJP: ok..i'll try to modify my answer. But could you explain me what's the difference between "copy objectts by reference" and "copy referencesby value"? I would like to understand that.

Comment: The difference is that in the first case you are talking about copying objects; in the second case you aren't, you are talking about copying references to objects, in other words you are making those references refer to *different* objects, rather than doing anything to the objects themselves. This shouldn't be hard to understand. Your edit is OK now, de-downvoting.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to copy an object use [`clone()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29)

if I misunderstood your question please comment

Comment: No you are correct, though i've tried making TimeLine implements Cloneable and added the method : public Object clone().... and when I am trying to make this.timeline = (TimeLine)timeline.clone() i get nullpointerexception.

Comment: public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
  return super.clone();
 }

Comment: please not, if you want to do a deep copy, you have to overwrite the clone method and implement it by yourself

Comment: So if I dont implement the method, how do I then do .clone() ?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [`clone`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_%28Java_method%29) method. (I've gone back and forth as to which documentation to cite, that is Wikipedia, it's treatment is more thorough. The [Java doc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_%28Java_method%29)'s are more official, of course).

Eg.

```
MyObject a = new MyObject();
a.setSomething( 2 );
MyObject b = a.clone();

// now b.getSomething().equals(a.getSomething()) (maybe == too, depends on class)
// and b.equals(a)
// b != a
```

Comment: Thanks, buy why to I get NullPointerException when I use it?

Comment: @cwallenpoole:is clone implemented like a deep clone operation? I mean, does it invoke clone automatically on all the objects stored inside MyObject?

Comment: @0verboze By default it is shallow, (I added the link to Wikipedia, tehy give some more info)