# Cloning lists in Java

Tags: java, list, generics, clone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to clone ArrayList and also clone its contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715650/how-to-clone-arraylist-and-also-clone-its-contents)

I have a `ArrayList<Widget>` that I would like to "deep" clone so that making modifications to any items in the original list does not have any effect on the items in the cloned list:

```
ArrayList<Widget> origList = getMyList();
ArrayList<Widget> cloneList = origList.clone();

// Remove the 5th Widget from the origina list
origList.remove(4);

// However, the cloneList still has the 5th Widget and is unchanged

// Change the id of the first widget
origList.get(0).setId(20);

// However in cloneList, the 1st Widget's ID is not 20
```

What's the best/safest way of accomplishing this? I imagine that it's not as simple as:

```
ArrayList<Widget> cloneList = origList.clone();
```

I imagine the fact that this is a built-in `ArrayList` type, plus the fact that its generic, are going to complicate things. I also imagine I will need to write a special `clone()` override for my `Widget` class?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**:
I'd also be completely receptive if there is a commons JAR out there that does this heavy lifting for me, so please feel free to make suggestions, however I would still like to know how to do this the ole' fashion way so I can learn ;-)

Comment: please do a search before posting questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a non-trivial task, I suggest you use one of the available libraries such as http://code.google.com/p/cloning/

See also: [Java: recommended solution for deep cloning/copying an instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156120/java-recommended-solution-for-deep-cloning-copying-an-instance)

If you want to see how it's done get an open-source library and look at the source :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to iterate over each item in the original list and clone each item individually, then add them to a new list of 'cloned' items.

Something like:

```
List<Widget> origList = getMyList();
List<Widget> clonedList = clone(origList);

private List<Widget> clone(List<Widget> listToClone) {
  List<Widget> clonedList = new LinkedList<Widget>();

  for (Widget widget : listToClone) {
    clonedList.add(widget.clone());
  }

  return clonedList;
}
```

For this to work you will have to have your `Widget` object implement the `Cloneable` interface, and the `clone()` method.  Nothing else is needed.

But again, as the other posters have said, many would argue that the `clone` implementation in Java isn't great to rely on, and is best avoided.

Answer (score 2):

Some authorities discourage the use of `clone`.  [Here is one link off google](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=71).  That's not to say don't do it, but just be aware of what you are getting yourself into, and be sure to test (well, always do that).

I would probably put a `deepCopy` method on the root class, and just do the copy the brute force way, with copy constructors.  A copy constructor is a constructor that takes an instance of the class in question, and creates a new instance, copying the internal state of the argument into the new instance.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at this: http://code.google.com/p/cloning/