# Deep copy java object with all sub-objects

Tags: java, clone, deep-copy

I want to find an efficient way to clone a big system object (planetary system in my case) with all its sub-objects. The sub-objects have coordinates and stuff like that, planets etc. So a deep copy, i guess..

I tried cloning and some serializable hacks, didn't seem to be working, the copy's sub-objects attributes didn't remain constant as I tried printing the copy's certain planets coordinates after i made the copy and the planets continued orbitting.

My main goal is to save a current state of the whole systems object positions, states etc. and recover back to it at any given time after the copy has been made.
Hope I haven't misunderstood anything..

Comment: This answer has some helpful solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156120/java-recommended-solution-for-deep-cloning-copying-an-instance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036/how-do-you-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-java

Answer (score 1):

If you must persist your objects and restore state at the later time you should use java serialization or for example [db4o](http://www.db4o.com/) (this is really easy to use).

Serialization should work also - every class you aggregate in your "universe" (and "universe" itself) should implement Serializable interface, and any field you don't want to serialize should be marked as `transient`.

Answer (score 1):

One approach I have used is to use the xstream package from Codehaus (http://x-stream.github.io/) to serialize/deserialize directly.  Something like:

```
XStream xs = new XStream();
MyObjectTree to;

 ///from is an instance of MyObjectTree
to = (MyObjectTree)xs.fromXML(xs.toXML(from));
```