# In Java, how to make a deep copy of an instance of Stack<MyElement> easily?

Tags: java, stack, clone, deep-copy

e.g.

```
class StackElement {
    String method;
    int state;
}

Stack<StackElement> stack;
```

I want to get a deep copy of this `stack`, which contains `StackElement` defined by myself.

1. Does Java provide a suitable API for this purpose ?
2. If not, how to implement it in a simple and general way ?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to follow these simple steps:

1. make your `StackElement` implement `Serializable`;
2. serialize the complete stack into a byte array;
3. deserialize right back into a deep copy.

The downside is less-than-top performance.

Do note that `Stack` is considered an archaeological artefact, obsoleted way back in Java 1.2 by `LinkedList`, which can be used as a stack. The reason it is obsoleted is that each method is `synchronized`, adding very little to thread safety of client code, but introducing a performance hit and even possible deadlocks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a special issue with your case, but you could look at some options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156120/java-recommended-solution-for-deep-cloning-copying-an-instance).