# Making a replica 2D array before I change it

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I've made a 2D array which is a map for a game. As the player moves around the map the Array changes slightly, but I'd like to be able to refer back to the original, unchanged Array. How can I do this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Of which type is the array?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29

Comment: What about saving a history of each tile of the map as a linked list?  That way you aren't saving duplicate data.

Answer (score 0):

If `arr` is a 2d `String` array:

```
String[][] copy = arr.clone();
```

Then, just make changes to `copy`.

If it is an array of objects, you may want to make a deep copy, i.e. making a copy of all the contained objects. But in your case, since `String`s are immutable, a `clone` will suffice. However, considering storing your data in classes instead of strings.

Comment: Sorry I should have said, it's a String Array

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a copy of each element, just the array, use

```
array.clone()
```

If you do need to copy each element, you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156120/java-recommended-solution-for-deep-cloning-copying-an-instance/2156367#2156367).