# Assigning an attribute to a parameter, but not by reference

Tags: java, parameters, attributes, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I'm using `TextStyle` and `Styler` to provide coloring in an SWT window I am creating.

I'm having a problem in my `Styler` method `applyChanges()`. The method (an abstract method built into `Styler` by the authors of SWT) takes a `TextStyle` object and applies formatting to it, for example, like this:

```
public void applyStyles(TextStyle textStyle) {
    textStyle.background = new Color(null, new RGB(102, 0, 58));
    //yada yada
}
```

However, instead of applying styles directly to it, I would like to assign an attribute that already carries all the styles. In other words, I am trying this:

```
public void applyStyles(TextStyle textStyle) {
    textStyle= this.textStyleAttributeStyle;

}
```

Unfortunately, though this is not working and I believe it has something to do with passing the attribute by reference because when I copy the attributes one by one, for example like

```
public void applyStyles(TextStyle textStyle) {
        textStyle.background= this.textStyleAttributeStyle.background;

    }
```

it works great!

So my question is, how can I provide a complete clone/copy of every attribute in `textStyleAttributeStyle` and copy it to the corresponding attribute in `textStyle` in the shortest amount of code?

Comment: _passing the attribute by reference_ No. Java is always by value. To achieve the effect of _by reference_, you'll need to pass a object that has a reference to the `textStyle` and change that, just like you do for `Color`.

Comment: Cloning/Copying properties of an object: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156120/java-recommended-solution-for-deep-cloning-copying-an-instance

Answer (score 0):

I think the [Java Deep Cloning Library](http://code.google.com/p/cloning/) could be usefull for you,

```
Cloner cloner=new Cloner();

MyClass clone=cloner.deepClone(o);
// clone is a deep-clone of o
```