# Adding objects (copied through Defensive copying using BeanUtils) in ArrayList giving stale data: Spring 3

Tags: java, list, spring-3, defensive-copy

```
public class CustomerDTO {
    private int customerId;
    private String customerName;
    private String customerAddress;

    public int getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }
    public void setCustomerId(int customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }
    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }
    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }
    public String getCustomerAddress() {
        return customerAddress;
    }
    public void setCustomerAddress(String customerAddress) {
        this.customerAddress = customerAddress;
    }
}
```

CustomerDAO class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collections;

public final class CustomerDAO {
    private CustomerDTO customer;

    public void setCustomer(CustomerDTO customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    //Trying to get copy of object with BeanUtils
    public final CustomerDTO getCustomer(int customerId){
        CustomerDTO origCustomer = _springContext.getBean(CustomerDTO.class);
        CustomerDTO targetCustomer=null;
        if("you get customer based on customer id") then "targetCustomer got initialized";
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(targetCustomer, origCustomer);//spring BeanUtils
    }

    //Trying to add object returned by above method into the list
    public final List<CustomerDTO> getCustomerList(List<Integer> customerIds){
        List<CustomerDTO> customerList = new ArrayList<CustomerDTO>();
        for(Integer id:customerIds){
            CustomerDTO customer = getCustomer(id);
            System.out.println("correct output: "+customer.getCustomerId());//getting correct output here
            customerList.add(customer);//Trying to add copied object in list
        }
        for(CustomerDTO customer: customerList){
            System.out.println("wrong output: "+customer.getCustomerId());//getting wrong output here
        }
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(customerList);
    }
}
```

In `CustomerDTO getCustomer(int customerId)` method, I am trying to return copy of CustomerDTO object by using Spring `BeanUtils.copyProperties(targetCustomer, origCustomer);`, But when I am adding these copied objects in list in method `List<CustomerDTO> getCustomerList(List<Integer> customerIds)` then I am getting strange behavior as mentioned in the comments. If I am removing `BeanUtils.copyProperties(targetCustomer, origCustomer);` then behavior is correct.

**Test case:**

```
getCustomerList with customerIds =[1,2,3,4]
```

**With copied objects**:  `BeanUtils.copyProperties(targetCustomer, origCustomer);`//spring BeanUtils

```
correct output: 1
correct output: 2
correct output: 3
correct output: 4
wrong output: 4
wrong output: 4
wrong output: 4
wrong output: 4
```

**Without copied objects:** `BeanUtils.copyProperties(targetCustomer, origCustomer);`//spring BeanUtils

```
correct output: 1
correct output: 2
correct output: 3
correct output: 4
wrong output: 1
wrong output: 2
wrong output: 3
wrong output: 4
```

**Could someone please explain me what is wrong or possible explanation for this behavior?**

**Updated: Purpose of using BeanUtils:**

I am trying to use defensive copy of the mutable object before returning the CustomerDTO object from the method `getCustomer()`. So I try to use shallow cloning following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2156367/1544069).

update: Removed the word Immutability as it was wrong to use.

Comment: Will be interesting to see how you are initializing your targetCustomer before passing to BeanUtils. I assume you are returning targetCustomer from getCustomer(int) method. By any change, you are returning the "same" instance of target Customer each time.

Comment: Where is the immutable object?  I don't see any final variables.

Comment: @Optional: I am fetching data from Database to initialize targetCustomer before passing to Bean Utils.

Comment: @tom: as per my knowledge, which is still small, I can not make CustomerDTO class final with spring, I could only have made few CustomerDAO methods final. I would appreciate if you could refer/tell me way to do so in Spring.

Comment: Downvoter: Please share your comment or answer the question.

Comment: @ritesh please share ur code to initialize targetCustomer. I guess you are "reusing" the same object and hence the problem

Comment: @Optional: I can not share requested piece of code for multiple reasons and believe me it has almost no effect on results of test cases. I have already solve the problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/17545377/1544069. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wrong output: 4
wrong output: 4
wrong output: 4
wrong output: 4
```

This could happen if the list is containing same object, then Why is list containing same object and how could following work?

```
correct output: 1
correct output: 2
correct output: 3
correct output: 4
```

origCustomer is containing reference to say CustomerDTO@60bc92, which is singleton maintained by spring, So it would always have same reference. Reference for targetCustomer will change. But BeanUtils.copyProperties(targetCustomer, origCustomer); will copy the properties of targetCustomer to origCustomer means CustomerDTO@60bc92.

```
for(Integer id:customerIds){
            CustomerDTO customer = getCustomer(id);
            System.out.println("correct output: "+customer.getCustomerId());//getting correct output here
            customerList.add(customer);//Trying to add copied object in list
        }

for(customer ids 1 to 4){
       customer will get reference CustomerDTO@60bc92 and will be updated based on customer ids
       so it is printing correct values 
       but it is adding same reference CustomerDTO@60bc92 to the list
}

 for(CustomerDTO customer: customerList){
            System.out.println("wrong output: "+customer.getCustomerId());//getting wrong output here
        }

for(all customer object in list which is same object reference and having latest value means 4){
      it is printing wrong value as 4
}
```

Now why origCustomer is being created from Spring context, like

```
CustomerDTO origCustomer = _springContext.getBean(CustomerDTO.class);
```

Because BeanUtils from spring needs default initialized spring bean.

Solution of this problem:

```
CustomerDTO origCustomer = new CustomerDTO();
```

and using BeanUtils from `org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils;`

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong tools.

Your problem is that you mixed up Spring beans with Java beans.

A Spring bean is a singleton and therefore you only have one `CustomerDTO` in your Spring context. The Spring context is not a replacement for a real DAO.

Either use a`Map` or a database in your DAO and don't try to use the Spring context for data storage and retrieval operations.

Comment: Could you please explain test case : "With Immutable Objects"?

Comment: Purpose of using BeanUtils: I am trying to use defensive copy of the mutable object before returning the CustomerDTO object from the method getCustomer(). So I try to use shallow cloning following this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2156367/1544069. I would appreciate if you could tell me right tools as well.

Comment: @ritesh Why do you think you have immutable objects? I don't see any immutability in your design.

Comment: @ritesh Found my error and corrected my answer. `BeanUtils.copyProperties()` is suitable for this use case. But you still try to use the Spring context for anything that it is not designed for.

Comment: I am really thankful to you for answering this question. I think Immutable object is creating some confusion. My intention is to make this method `CustomerDTO getCustomer(int customerId)` return Immutable object which would be CustomerDTO,which I am trying to with BeanUtils, and then I am adding these objects into the list in method `List<CustomerDTO> getCustomerList(List<Integer> customerIds)`. hope this adds some clarity

Comment: I think I am using spring context only in `origCustomer` which would be needed for `BeanUtils.copyProperty()` otherweise it will throw error. By instantiating beans through spring context, I am initializing them to default values.

Comment: Do you still think that I am mixing Spring bean with java bean? I understand the singleton concept but then why is it not reflecting in test case results?