# Does the iterator give me a deep copy?

Tags: java, iterator, copy, deep-copy

I hope I am just confused now because my Java program behaves strange.

I have the following code:

```
Iterator<Entry<DateTime, Double>> itCur = this.curIntervalValues.entrySet().iterator();

Entry<DateTime, Double> last = null;
while (itCur.hasNext()){
  Entry<DateTime, Double> curr =  itCur.next();
  //more code between
  last = curr;
}
```

My question is quite simple: does `last = curr;` makes a deep copy of `curr`?
Or does `last` now every time changes if `curr` changes?

Comment: You haven't said how your Java program behaves, or what `curIntervalValues` is, or in what way you expect `curr` to change. It would help if you could post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: what data structure `curIntervalValues` represents ?

Comment: @sanbhat looks like a `Map`.

Comment: yes, it curIntervalValues is a Map

Comment: Exactly it is regular behavior - you're working not with objects, but with reference objects.

Comment: @zvzdhk you mean that the regular behavior is the statement in second question at bottom.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I mean that her Java program does not behave strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When executing `last = curr`, `last` won't be a copy of the current item, it will be **the current item** reference. So if you edit its fields, you will edit the fields of the `curr` object reference as well. For example, if you execute

```
System.out.println(last.getSomeProperty());
last.setSomeProperty(newValue);
System.out.println(last.getSomeProperty());
```

It will print

```
oldValue
newValue
```

And your reference will be modified in your collection as well.

> does `last` now every time changes if `curr` changes?

Short answer: yes.

---

By your comment, looks like you want a clone of the data handled by `curr`. If so, I would recommend following one of the approaches stated here: [Java: recommended solution for deep cloning/copying an instance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2156120/1065197)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there an easy way to make a deep copy of curr?

Comment: @cruxi answer updated. Please refer to the link I've provided.

Answer (score 1):

`Entry<DateTime, Double>` is an object, therefore it is stored by reference, meaning that only the object's location in memory is stored in the variable. So yes, if you do `last = curr`, `last` will change if you alter `curr`.