# Copy the entire Object which doesn't implemented clone in java?

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils

I want to copy an entire object which doesn't implement clone method.

The `BeanUtils.copyProperties(obj1, obj2)` does the copy however makes the process tedious as we need to register which are the value will be `null`.

ex:

```
 ConvertUtils.register(new DateConverter(null), Date.class);
 BeanUtils.copyProperties(emp1, emp2);
```

where the `emp2` will have some date methods where the property might be null..

Assume there might be `100` of properties might be null and we need to just ignore the same..

I need the exact copy of the object.

Could someone suggest the best way or a utility to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried doing it with reflection?

Comment: Have you looked at Spring's `BeanWrapper`?

Comment: Can you please post some sample code snippet on how to do with reflection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sanbhat's answer is the only way to achieve 100% clone. Be careful, serialization and deserialization are slow processes.

Comment: Thanks for the details...if the process is slow is there is any alternatives...such as Cloner cloner=new Cloner();
Object cloned = cloner.deepClone(someObject);  (OR) // or with Apache Commons
cloned = org.apache.commons.lang. SerializationUtils.clone(someObject);

Comment: AFAIK, if you want 100% cloning, all the libs drill down to serialization. I dont see any magic happening there :)

Answer (score 3):

You can serialize the object and deserialize it back. [Serialization->Deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156120/java-recommended-solution-for-deep-cloning-copying-an-instance) is alternative to **deep cloning**

Comment: Instead of doing it manually is there is any utility will do this?

Comment: It's three lines of code. But your classes must all be `Serializable`.

Comment: The class is serializable..can you paste the three lines to look into?

Comment: If you google for serialization in java, you will get bunch of examples