# Java: Copy attributes from one object instance to another?

Tags: java, object, reference, deep-copy, shallow-copy

Say you have

```
public class Car{
  private Engine m_eng;
  public Car(){

  }

  public Engine getEngine(){
    return m_eng;
  }

  public void setEngine(Engine engine){
    m_eng = engine;
  }
}

public class Engine{
  private String m_name;
  public Engine(){};
  public Engine(String name){ m_name = name;}

  public String getName(){
    return m_name;
  }
  public void setName(String name){
    m_name = name;
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
  Engine eng1 = new Engine("abc");
  Car car1 = new Car();
  car1.setEngine(eng1);
  Car car2 = new Car();
  car2.setEngine(car1.getEngine());
}
```

Question: are the engine of car1 and car2 referring to the same instance of Engine, or when I do `car2.setEngine(car1.getEngine())`, it automatically make a deep copy of car1.getEnginer() and set to car2 ?

Comment: You can test this with `==`.

Comment: It is the same instance. As @SotiriosDelimanolis said, you can easily test it using `==`.

Comment: If you've not done it intentionally, it certainly isn't a deepcopy in Java.

Comment: Sounds like a homework/exam question...

Comment: Java allways pass by value, i.e. by parameter it makes a copy of the reference "pointing" to the same value. There is a lot of discussion wheter this should be called passByValue or passByReferende. The Java Language Reference calls it pass by value. You can read a good article on this issue under [Java is Pass by Value and Not Pass by Reference](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/java-pass-value-and-not-pass-0)

Comment: @wolfrevo while this is true, this does not apply for what OP is looking for. Refer to my answer to have a better understanding on the *copy* term used in this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

car1--------------->eng1

```
car2.setEngine(car1.getEngine());
```

results in

car1--------------->eng1 <------------------car2

thereby pointing to same engine instance

Comment: This is the only answer that explains in some detail why the engine in both cars is the same object reference.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah sure these will be same instance.

Answer (score 3):

There is no deep copy.  Both `Car` instances reference the same instance of `Engine`.

Answer (score 3):

As noted by other people, when you do

```
car2.setEngine(car1.getEngine())
```

The `engine` in `car2` will be the same object reference as in `car1`. This is easily tested by using `==`:

```
System.out.println(car2.getEngine() == car1.getEngine()); //prints "true"
```

> when I do `car2.setEngine(car1.getEngine())` *it automatically make a deep copy of `car1.getEngine()` and set to `car2`?*

Be careful here, since when executing that statement **there's no copy of the object reference**, it is not a deep copy **nor a shallow copy**, it is **the same object reference**. This means, if you modify the state of the engine in one of the cars, then the engine in the other car gets modified (since is the same object reference):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Engine eng1 = new Engine("abc");
    Car car1 = new Car();
    car1.setEngine(eng1);
    Car car2 = new Car();
    car2.setEngine(car1.getEngine());
    //additional code to show the last statement
    car2.getEngine().setName("foo");
    System.out.println(car2.getEngine().getName()); //prints "foo"
    System.out.println(car1.getEngine().getName()); //prints "foo" too
    System.out.println(eng1.getName());  //prints "foo" since it is the same object reference used from the beginning
}
```

Check here to know about how to make copies of object references: [Java: recommended solution for deep cloning/copying an instance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2156120/1065197)

Answer (score 2):

There is no deep copy. both reference are refering to same object try to use == operator to compare two objects.

```
 Engine eng1 = new Engine("abc");
  Car car1 = new Car();
  car1.setEngine(eng1);   //here you have set the reference eng1 which is pointing to the object abc in heap
  Car car2 = new Car();
  car2.setEngine(car1.getEngine());// here you are getting the reference of the object which is in the heap and setting it in car2 Object
```