# Cloning different objects in Java

Tags: java, clone

I have two database tables which are mirror images of each other. The reason for this is one table stores "CURRENT" values and the other tables saves "ARCHIVED" values. I use hibernate as  the ORM tool. The tables have 20 columns each . The business requirement is that the values in the "current" table gets house-keeped at specific intervals to "archive" table. It is cumbersome to copy the values from "current" object to "archive" object. Is there a way in JAVA to clone objects of different types (current object to archive object)? The elements of the objects are identical.

Comment: There is `Cloneable` for this, but really, this is a job better left to a stored procedure in the database; it will do this much more efficiently than any Java code will ever achieve.

Comment: So you want two instances of different classes (with no direct inheritance relationship) to have the same field (=instance variable) values?

Comment: Cloneable is for the same class copy. If i understand that right, that are two different classes or is that my fault?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: recommended solution for deep cloning/copying an instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156120/java-recommended-solution-for-deep-cloning-copying-an-instance)

Comment: Crazy as it may sound, two different classes really with no common parentage.

Comment: I'd say pass a reference to the live one into the archive, and have the archive launch a thread that periodically copies the live one's contents... BUT BEWARE OF THREADSAFETY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/)

It has usefull method to [copy properties](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) between two distinct without hierarchy relationship. This should work as long as the propperties of both beans have the same names.

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(Object dest, Object orig);
```

Copy property values from the origin bean to the destination bean for **all cases where the property names are the same**.

Comment: Thnx. Will have a look.

Answer (score 1):

I go with what fge suggested in the comment, however, you can just create a constructor and pass to it the "current" object.

```
class ArchiveEntry{
   private String dummy;

   public ArchiveEntry(CurrentEntry entry) {
      this.dummy = entry.getDummy(); 
   }
}
```

Comment: Thnx. The whole point was that I was copying the properties of the "current" object to "archive" object in my DAO code which wasn't looking pretty. This sound like a good idea. Basics, sometimes I forget. Thanks again. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the dozer mapper framework. Supports deep cloning using configuration.