# How to deepclone Map with List as value

Tags: java, clone

Is this the best way to **deepclone** this data structure example: `Map<String, List<Object>>`?

```
Map<String, List<Object>> mapB = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<Object>>();
for(String key: mapA.keySet()){
      mapB.put(key, new ArrayList<Object>());
      mapB.get(key).addAll(mapA.get(key));
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the best way to deepclone this data structure

More or less, yes. You can make it a bit shorter using the ArrayList constructor that takes a source Collection as argument, and a bit more efficient (but more wordy) by iterating key-value pairs instead of looking up each key again, but it amounts to the same thing.

```
Map<String, List<Object>> mapB = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, List<Object>> entry : mapA.entrySet()) {
    mapB.put(entry.getKey(), new ArrayList<>(entry.getValue()));
}
```

Comment: I like that Map.Entry approach, thanks! Regarding the new ArrayList<>(Collection) I've read it that using it would not make a deepcopy, could I be mistaken?

Comment: @GuilhE `new ArrayList<>(...)` does the same thing as your original code: `new ArrayList<>()` followed by `addAll(...)`. It creates a new list which contains the uncloned instances of the existing objects. There is sadly no built-in way in Java to clone arbitrary `Object`s, at least not without having some knowledge of their type, but if you need that, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156120/java-recommended-solution-for-deep-cloning-copying-an-instance) for some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine if you don't want deep copy of contaning objects.

Comment: Yes in this case I just want to deepcopy the Lists because I'll be performing remove operations and I don't want to change the original Lists. The objects inside the Lists won't be changed. If my desire was to perform an "infinite" deepcopy is there any good lib to do so? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method of deep cloning is to use serialization. The following method shows how this is done:

```
    public Object deepClone(Object obj) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.writeObject(obj);

        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
        return ois.readObject();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The apache commons lang [SerializationUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3.2/org/apache/commons/lang3/SerializationUtils.html) offers a generic method to do this.

Both ways assume that all objects in your object graph implement serializable.