# deep cloning in java showing null pointer exception

Tags: java, clone

hi im trying to make a simple deep cloning example in java

```
public class Deepcloning implements Cloneable
{
    public Shallowcloning shallowcopy;
    public Deepcloning() {
    }
    public Shallowcloning getShallowcopy() {
        return shallowcopy;
    }
    public void setShallowcopy(Shallowcloning shallowcopy) {
        this.shallowcopy = shallowcopy;
    }
    public String getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }
    public void setEmployee(String employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }
    private String employee;

    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException{

        Deepcloning shls=(Deepcloning)super.clone();
        shls.setShallowcopy((Shallowcloning)shallowcopy.clone());
        return shls;
    }
}
```

and in the main implementation method

```
public class Clonningimplementation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            Deepcloning dp1 = new Deepcloning();
            dp1.setEmployee("solomon");

            dp1.getShallowcopy().setAge(11);
            dp1.getShallowcopy().setSalary(3000);


            System.out.println("orignal copy employee" + dp1.getEmployee());
            System.out.println("orignal copy employee" + dp1.getShallowcopy().getAge());
            System.out.println("orignal copy employee" + dp1.getShallowcopy().getSalary());
        } catch (ClonenotSupportedException e) {
            e.printstacktrace();
        }

        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

while running this code im getting null pointer exception. in deep cloning im supposed to clone the reference that too i have done still didnt getting the result any help would be appreciated

Comment: Exception stack trace??

Comment: You should read this q/a: [Java: recommended solution for deep cloning/copying an instance](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2156120/1065197)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dp1.getShallowcopy().setAge(11);
```

You are directly calling methods on `shallowcopy` reference without instantiating it. By default it's value is null. calling methods on null reference will give NPE.

You need to do

```
Deepcloning dp1=new Deepcloning(); dp1.setEmployee("solomon");
dp1.setShallowcopy(new Shallowcloning ());
dp1.getShallowcopy().setAge(11);;
dp1.getShallowcopy().setSalary(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default every object initializes to null and is your shallowcopy.

You are calling getter for shallowcopy as below:

```
dp1.getShallowcopy().setAge(11);
```

But you have never setted value for shallowCopy and hence when you call this method it gets evaluated as `null.setAge(11);` and calling a method on null gives you null pointer exception.

To avoid this, you might need to set Shallowcloning using

```
Deepcloning dp1=new Deepcloning(); 
dp1.setEmployee("solomon");
dp1.setShallowcopy(...);
```

This applies to clone method as well.

Comment: and whats the solution

Comment: See the last few lines of my answer.

Comment: @user3878073 the solution is: **don't reinvent the wheel**. There are frameworks that help you to do this.