# Overriding cloned object completely in java

Tags: java, clone

I'm cloning one object into another object and then trying to change only two parameters in new object. But still the original object is getting changed. I just want both copies should be separate. Here is my code

```
Subgroup sg1 = new Subgroup();
sg1.setFname("Vali");
sg1.setMname("Sheik");
sg1.setLname("Sha");
Group g1 = new Group();
g1.setSg(sg1);
try { 
     Group g2 = (Group) g1.clone();
     Subgroup sg1 = g2.getSg();
     sg2.setFname("parvez");
     sg2.setMname("syed");
     sg2.setLname("khan");
     g2.setSg(sg2);
     System.out.println(g1);
     System.out.println(g2);
} catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {  
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Both cases it's printing first object only.

Clone method in group class

```
 Protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
     return super.clone();
 }
```

Comment: Please add the source code of your classes (Group and Subgroup)

Comment: Show your clone method please

Comment: Jens, I have updated

Comment: @RC it's just setters and getters. I'm using my mobile to post the question.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036/how-do-you-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-java?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By overriding cloning method you will create a copy of your object.

Please find below example:

**Subgroup.java**

```
public class Subgroup {

    private String fname;
    private String mname;
    private String lname;

    //getter-setter

    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        Subgroup sg = new Subgroup();
        sg.setFname(this.fname);
        sg.setMname(this.mname);
        sg.setLname(this.lname);
        return sg;
    }

     //to-string

}
```

**Group.java**

```
public class Group {

    private Subgroup sg;

    //getter-setter

    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        Group g = new Group();
        g.setSg((Subgroup) this.sg.clone());
        return g;
    }
    //to-string

}
```

**TestMain.java**

```
public class TestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Subgroup sg1 = new Subgroup();
        sg1.setFname("Vali");
        sg1.setMname("Sheik");
        sg1.setLname("Sha");
        Group g1 = new Group();
        g1.setSg(sg1);
        try {
            Group g2 = (Group) g1.clone();
            Subgroup sg2 = g2.getSg();
            sg2.setFname("parvez");
            sg2.setMname("syed");
            sg2.setLname("khan");
            g2.setSg(sg2);
            System.out.println(g1);
            System.out.println(g2);
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `clone()` in class Object does only shallow copy, instead you need to check how to do [deep cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156120/java-recommended-solution-for-deep-cloning-copying-an-instance)

Comment: You can use commons-lang SerializationUtils ,   Group g2 = (Group) SerializationUtils.serialize(g1);  But all classes should be Serializable