# How to create a copy and return its object without using clone?

Tags: java, clone

i was wondering how to create a copy and return its object without using the clone function.

```
    public double[] Mean(double[][] data) {

    double[] x = data[0].clone();
```

Comment: why not use clone?

Comment: Please help me.

Comment: @PrinceofPersia please answer the question .... also, what do you want to copy, arrays or Object

Comment: Dear @PrinceofPersia - show a bit of patience. You see, first of all, your question is kinda strange. clone works nicely for the example you provided; so dont push us on providing a solution to a strange question ...

Comment: Use this topic hope you can get all details [clonning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156120/java-recommended-solution-for-deep-cloning-copying-an-instance)

Comment: @PrinceofPersia - did you manage to get it working?

Comment: yh thanks everybody for partcipating

Comment: Sorry someone game me -1 thats y i was impatient

Comment: @PrinceofPersia probably because your question is a bit broad. Don't forget to accept the answer that help you the most.

Comment: @PrinceofPersia if you think an answer is good, you should accept it (the `v` under the answer score). that way others know the answer works

Comment: ok it says i have to wait 5 min

Comment: @PrinceofPersia wait, I'm confused. Which answer did you choose? it's showing me both of them as accepted [o.o]

Comment: they both helped me

Comment: but which helped **more**?

Comment: @PrinceofPersia I might add that `Arrays` does it much more efficiently

Comment: Equally, they both helped probably Mark

Comment: @PrinceofPersia you misunderstand me. there's more than one way of doing almost anything in Java, but there are much fewer *right* ways. cloning an object is done via `.clone()` which you didn't want. the second `'right'` way of copying an `array` is using `Arrays.copyOf()`. 

using a for `loop` is a brute-force method which is less efficient in terms of runtime than `Arrays.copyOf()`...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127620/discussion-between-itamar-green-and-prince-of-persia).

Comment: He wanted to know how it worked. If someone wants to know how to build a car without having the leading expert build it for him you don't give him the address of yet another expert who can build a car for him, you show him how it's done. Sure, brute force is slower, but it's also very simple to understand, which was the point. But honestly this discussion is way off topic, so Prince just choose Itamars as the correct answer, we'll leave the other up too and everyone is happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public double[] colMean(double[][] data) {
    double[] x = new double[data[0].length];
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i] = data[0][i];
    }
    return x;
}
```

Odd that you only want to copy data[0] though, but whatever...

Comment: Thanks g, this was helpful

Comment: Nice, recreating the wheel but simple

Comment: @AxelH more like an `Array` of wheels ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
double copy = Arrays.copyOf(data[0],data[0].length);
```

Which will, as the name states, return a `copy` of the array. 
*NOTE: this will only work for arrays, since it's a method from `java.util.Arrays` (self-explanatory)*